# Bison reset line number for each new file

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I have a simple parser implementation using `GNU bison` and `flex`. It works fine and I can parse multiple files from command line

```
./program file1.m file2.m
```

and I load the files in reverse order (that doesn't matter much).

However the problem is the line numbers I get (let's say when there is a syntax error in `file1.m`) will be the linember in `file1` plus the number of lines in `file2`.

So bison is not resetting the line number after each file. How can achieve that? I googled a bit and found `yy_flush_buffer`, but I am not really sure how to use it or if it is in fact what I need.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line numbers are maintained by the code generated from `flex` in the variable `yylineno`. These line numbers are one way or another passed to the code from `bison`. There may be other ways of resetting the line numbering, but old school method is setting the variable `yylineno` to `1` before calling `yyparse` on a new file. You will have to use `%option yylineno` to let `flex` keep line numbers at a slight performance penalty, but you probably did that already.

Comment: Thank you. `yyset_lineno(int)` didn't work. it says the good old undefined reference. I have `%option yylineno` in the lexer. I don't why the function is not available. Anyways I managed to fix it by setting `yylineno` to 1 for every file before calling `yyparse`. Thank you.

Comment: however it would be nice to know how I can use `yyset_lineno(int)`. Seeting the raw yylineno doesn't llok very nice. However this is just curiosity. Nothing absolutely necessary.

Comment: Hmm, maybe different version of `flex`. I'd stick to old school setting `yylineno`, the `yyset_lineno` is hardly any better as it does exactly the same thing. I'm going to remove the suggestion of `yyset_lineno`. I did add you should use `%option yylineno`.